# Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate when distribute app

Tags: ios, flutter

I used A's signing certificate to distribute the app before.Then changed it to B's signing certificate

It was successfully archived. I was stuck at last step which showed "Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate"

I can't delete all certificates cause there are other people use mac

Tried following solutions which are not working

1. In accounts and downloaded manual profiles
2. delete B's certificate in key access

Do anyone know
how to solve it? or how to update the signing certificate in Provisioning profile?
Thank you so much

Comment: Was A associated with a different developer account to B?  If so, the bundle ID for the app will be registered in A's developer account.  You will need to use a different bundle ID and create a new provisioning profile (Xcode can do this for you)

Comment: Though it is the different account but they are in same developer team should it use different bundle ID ?